# Represent tabular data (field heading then data) semantically without using a table

Tags: html, semantics

I'm coding a responsive & semantic HTML5 webpage. However, I've just hit a snag:

There's a piece of design that would normally be respresented as tabular data within the HTML (i.e. a heading and corresponding data) but it would be impossible to use tables in this case due to the visual design/layout requirements.

Is there a HTML alternative to using tables that can, semantically speaking, represent tabular well with assistive technologies e.g. screenreaders?

At the moment I'm running with:

`<p>
    <strong>Heading 1</strong>: <span>Data 1</span>
</p>
<p>
    <strong>Heading 2</strong>: <span>Data 2</span>
</p>`

Not the best solution, but it does allow me to fulfill the visual design requirements.

Many thanks.

Comment: It would be more constructive to consider what to do with the visual design/layout requirements. Just like you can format things in a tabular way in CSS even when the `table` element is used, you can format a `table` in a non-tabular way.

Comment: I disagree with the close vote for 'primarily opinion-based'. This is a good direct question which has factual answers.

Comment: There is one element in HTML for tabular data, `table`. Asking what is the best way, or what are the different ways (it is not clear which of these is asked), for marking up tabular data without using `table` is heavily opinion-based.

Comment: (And if I formed an opinion on it, I would want to know first what kind of tabular data we have, what its context is, what will be done with it, and how it might be formatted.)

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 there's a strict separation between semantics and presentation. Most 'default' presentational effects are just that - rules in the browser's default stylesheet.

If your data is semantically a table, use a `table` element by all means. If default table rendering **really** does not fit (I would actually be surprised, given what you can achieve with for example the `table-layout` rules), feel free to override it:

```
table.customtable, table.customtable tr {
  display:block;           /* overrides the defaults of 'table' and 'table-row' */
}
table.customtable td {
  display:inline-block;    /* overrides the default value of 'table-cell' */
}
```

This keeps the semantics the same but allows you full freedom on the layout end.

Comment: This makes sense (except for the vague speak about “semantics”) but does not answer the question (which calls for opinions on markup for tabular data without using `table`).

Comment: @niels-keurentjes: looks interesting. So I presume that converts ALL cells to blocks/inline blocks without any cross-browser issues? Also, would I need to reset any of the thead/tbody/tfoot wrappers too do you think? Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Iamme this is internally how the browser decides to render like a table, so yes overriding it has been standardized since IE8 or so when IE also started respecting all possible values for `display`.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I'm skipping the [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/219504) - given the second paragraph of the question ('normally I would use tables here') he's obviously only asking about HTML alternatives because he doesn't realize CSS can do it just fine.

Comment: I did consider the table reforming route, but remember reading about browser problems with that approach some time ago. My site must work on IE7+, and is fully responsive, so any IE8+ solutions wouldn't be possible. But perhaps my information is wrong. Will try the following and see what can be done:

`table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
    display: block; 
}`

Comment: Media queries [don't even work below IE9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries), so good luck with supporting IE7 (global market share: 0.11%, lower than IE6) for a responsive site - you'll have to go mobile-last by definition. I'm not sure what the exact support is in IE7 so do give it a try anyway - I know it doesn't support `inline-block` but it may very well fully support this scenario.